# Fibonacci series sequence in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, logic, fibonacci

I want to write a Fibonacci sequence program in ruby without using the recursion.
can you please help me to write this function.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Ruby has several solutions.

Comment: BTW, as your question is currently written it's basically _"can you please write this function for me"_. Without further explanation, it's hard to tell where you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fibonacci(n)
  final = []
  (0..n).each_with_index do |i, _|
    next final << i if i.zero? || i == 1
    final << final[i - 1] + final[i - 2]
  end
  final
end

puts fibonacci(10)
```

Comment: This code is not ruby code by any mean, even if it’s understood by ruby parser. Downvoted.